# DoVoid Leaving Transaction in 'Pending' Status

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Using the PayPal Express Checkout API's to create an order, authorise it, and then when the goods are shipped we are able to call DoCapture, however if we don't have the item in stock we call 'DoVoid'.

Every API call (include the DoVoid) returns success from PayPal, however we've been informed by customers that the Payment Status remains 'pending' in the PayPal overview screen.

If a user clicks 'details' in the overview screen they can see two transactions (one which returns the funds), however the actual 'order' isn't updated.

Does anyone know:

1. Is there an additional API call that needs to be made?
2. The best mechanism for getting assistance from PayPal?

Comment: Are you calling DoVoid on the Order or on the Authorization? (As an aside; PayPal provides API assistance via https://www.paypal.com/mts/ )

Comment: Thanks Robert - it looks like this was issue, I am void the AUTH not the order itself. If you like post as Answer so I can accept + vote!